# How to use "as" while exporting a library?

Tags: dart

I've a file, `foo.dart` which is exporting some libraries.

```dart
export 'dart:convert'; // Works
export 'dart:math' as math; // Error
```

But as you can see there's an error while using `as` in export.

Comment: What do you want `export 'dart:math' as math` to do?

Comment: @jamesdlin I want to import `foo.dart` in my `main.dart` file and wanna use `math.pi` there. Actually I've around 50s of import statements in my main.dart file, so I thought I could put them in a `foo.dart` file and import just `foo.dart`.

Comment: @jamesdlin I think this can be done using `part` and `part of`, will that be a good way?

Comment: It cannot be done, not with part files either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot export a namespace.

Exports cannot have an `as`.
The effect of an `as prefix` on an *import* is to declare a namespace in the library and import the imported library into that namespace.
There is nothing similar you can do for exports because you cannot export a namespace at all, the concept does not exist in the language. You can only export declarations.

This also prevents nested namespaces, which you could get if you could export a namespace, and then import or export it with a new prefix as well.